# How could I add new string while keeping the tab line?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I tried to add new string using shell script when the code line have "MSG_LOG".
I did add new string at the new line using this shell script,

```
#!/bin/bash

############Set File Name
fileName=$1
echo ">>>>Set_FileName is done"
echo ">>>>fileName is    ${fileName}"

############Get Elements
lineNumArr=(`grep -n "MSG_LOG" $fileName | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`)
echo ">>>>Getting LineNumArr is done"
for lineNum in "${lineNumArr[@]}"
do
############Replace logger
        sed -i "${lineNum} a printf('MSG_Log is show');" $fileName
        echo ">>>>Replace_logger is Done"
done
echo ">>>>for loop is closed"
exit
```

But it doesn't keep tabs on existing lines of code.
For Example, I want to make my .cpp file like this,

```
#include<iostream>
int main(void){
  bool value=true;
....
     if(value){
        MSG_LOG("VALUE IS TRUE");
        printf('MSG_LOG is show');
      }
....
```

But when I actuate this shell script, the result is...

```
#include<iostream>
int main(void){
  bool value=true;
....
     if(value){
        MSG_LOG("VALUE IS TRUE");
printf('MSG_LOG is show');
      }
....
```

How can I add new code while preserving the tablines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the same amount of withespace as the previous line when adding a new line.

You want something like this

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)(MSG_LOG\(.*\);)(.*)$/\1\2\3\n\1printf("MSG_LOG is show");/g'
```

If I understood correctly.

You don't have to invoke `sed` once per line as it loops over the entire file.

Also, you need double quotes in `printf`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Then If there is MSG_LOG with different tabs, can't the corresponding tab be applied?

Comment: This is for any number of tabs, spaces, etc. before MSG_LOG

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, you can duplicate the original line containing `MSG_LOG` and then replace the text, this will keep the tab spacing in place.

```
$ sed "/MSG_LOG/{p;s/[[:alpha:]].*/printf('MSG_LOG is show');/}" "$fileName"
```

Comment: WARNING: this will match MSG_LOG in other situations not only when it's invoked